# Need to find out user and details of the mysql db server which is failed connection

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

in Azure monitoring need to find out which user and server details for the failed connections in mysql dbs.

Is there any query to find out and user details.

also once we find out user and details we need to add that logic into logic app.

Comment: thanks Daniel, can you please suggest for mysql failed connection in azure portl how to find username and connection ip d details

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to your SQL server overview page and know your username under the name of server admin.

[image]

and can reset the password as mentioned in the below image.

[image]

Following the above way you can add the details to connect to your SQL Server in logic apps

Comment: Thanks Swetha , for failed connections mysql we  have configured the alerts, for business owners team we need to provide the details with failed connections user which is failed and Ip address and other details from Azure mointoring portal, and then need to automate in weekly report through email to that team, any suggestions how to get it thanks.

Comment: Any suggestion for mysql db failed connections details, user details IP address and then need to schedule into logic app

Comment: can anyone suggest for this azure mysqldb slow running query logic app